# Is `PYTHONPATH` really an environment variable?

Tags: python, environment-variables, pythonpath

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) for `sys.path` state the following:

> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

So my understanding here is that `PYTHONPATH` is an *environment variable*. Environment variables can be printed out in Powershell using the following command:

```
PS> echo $ENV:VARIABLENAME
```

However when I do `$ENV:PYTHONPATH` I get no output. If I try to access `PYTHONPATH` from a python terminal, I get a `KeyError`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python310\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

However, I know `PYTHONPATH` is defined *somewhere*, because its value does appear when I use `sys.path`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Python310\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\Python310', 'C:\\Users\\aa\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\scons-4.4.0-py3.10.egg', 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\colorama-0.3.2-py3.10.egg', 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

If `PYTHONPATH` is truly an environment variable, why can't I access it using either Powershell or `os` in my Python interpreter?

Comment: No, Python simply supplies a default value if `PYTHONPATH` is unset. The documentation you quoted does explain this.

Comment: @tripleee What typically sets `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: By default there is nothing in `PYTHONPATH`. If you set something as value for `PYTHONPATH`, then this something is added to `sys.path` and Python will look for imports in these directories.

Comment: Ok, thanks, if one of you guys can formulate that into a full answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable PYTHONPATH is an environment variable which you can set to add additional directories where python will look for modules and packages. This variable is not set by default and not needed for Python to work because it it already knows where to find its standard libraries (sys.path).

But if for any reason you need some custom Python libraries that you do not want to install, you can `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/my/modules/` to add `/path/to/my/modules/` on Python will then know where to find those custom modules.

And this time, if you print again sys.path, it will display you the newly added modules.